# NHibernate QueryOver with MaxResult, Group By and Order By

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I'm trying to convert a SQL query to NHibernate QueryOver syntax, but I don't understand how to sort by the count projection.

This is what the SQL Query looks like:

```
select top 10 v.intVoteUserID, COUNT(v.intVoteUserID)
from Group_MessageVotes v
where v.dtmVote > :date
group by v.intVoteUserID
order by COUNT(v.intVoteUserID) desc
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can simply repeat the projection in the OrderBy-clause.

The following query will give you an `IList<object[]>` where the first element of each item is the id and the second is the count.

```
var result = session.QueryOver<GroupMessageVotes>()
.Select(
    Projections.Group<GroupMessageVotes>(e => e.intVoteUserID),
    Projections.Count<GroupMessageVotes>(e => e.intVoteUserID)
    )
.OrderBy(Projections.Count<GroupMessageVotes>(e => e.intVoteUserID)).Desc
.Take(10)
.List<object[]>();
```

Comment: Are all these generic arguments required?

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger I think they are required for the lambda expressions. It is possible to write `Projections.Count("intVoteUserID")` instead, but I prefer the first option.

Comment: It should be possible to write `Projections.Count(e => e.intVoteUserID)`.

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger Yes, you are right. Funny that I didn't see that before. I fixed my answer to accomodate that.

Comment: Hm, the signature doesn't match. It`s `Count(Expression<Func<object>> expression);` instead of `Count<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression);`